# Can mprotect set the stack itself as executable?

Tags: linux, executable, stack

I'm taking my first steps in memory exploitation in Linux. I'm following a tutorial for a practice VM(`$ uname -r -> 3.13.0-32-generic`)

The tutorial makes a call to `mprotect` to set a certain region of memory executable, then uses `read` to manually input some shellcode.

I occurred to me that perhaps I could load my shellcode on the stack using the buffer and use `mprotect` to set the buffer region on the stack as executable and return to it. But that throws an error for reasons I'm not sure of.

In short, this call to `mprotect` works:

```
# mprotect: set memory executable
payload += p(0x080523e0) # mprotect addr
payload += p(0x08048882) # return to: pop, pop, pop, retn
payload += p(0xb7ffd000) # arg1: address of 'mapped' region
payload += p(0x2000)     # arg2: length
payload += p(0x7)        # arg3: rwx
```

But this call fails:

```
# mprotect: set memory executable
payload += p(0x080523e0) # mprotect addr
payload += p(0xbffff6c0) # return to shellcode in buffer on stack
payload += p(0xbffff6c0) # arg1: beginning of shellcode on stack
payload += p(0x2000)     # arg2: length
payload += p(0x7)        # arg3: rwx
```

Stepping through `mprotect` in that second example shows me that it takes an error jump:

```
=> 0x80523fa <mprotect+26>: jae    0x8053870 <__syscall_error>
```

As the only difference between the two is the address I want to set executable, I'm wondering if it's simply that `mprotect` can't set the stack as executable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`mprotect`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mprotect) can be used to make the stack executable.

See, for example:

- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/enable-execute-stack-mprotect.c
- http://rethinkdb.com/blog/handling-stack-overflow-on-custom-stacks/

You can troubleshoot further by examining the value of `errno` after the `mprotect` call.